# Required components for WCF selfhost?

Tags: c#, .net, installation

My service(TCP) have bin installed in IIS7 before and this is the requirements for that :

```
Internet  Information Services
- Web Management Tools (all)
- Wold Wide Web Services
-- Application Development Features (all - CGI)
-- Common Http Features (all)
-- Health and Diagnostics
--- HTTP Logging
--- Request Monitor
-- Performance Features
--- Static Content Compression
-- Security
--- Basic Authentication
--- Client Certificate Mapping Authentication
--- IIS Client Certificate Mapping Authentication
--- Request Filtering
--- URL Authorization
--- Windows Authentication
Microsoft .NET framework 3.0
- Windows Communication Foundation HTTP Activation (for WAS)
- Windows Communication Foundation Non-HTTP Activation
Windows Process Activation Service
- .NET Environment
- Configuration APIs
- Process Model
```

Now I have changed to .NET WCF Selfhost and this makes me wonder what components that are required? Is it true that I can remove Internet Information Services and the Windows Process Activation Service?

Is all I need to keep the .NET framework X.0?

Comment: Yes, you should not need IIS. but I would recommend that you should assert this by testing on a fresh server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF Self Hosting absolutely does not require IIS or any other service. It only requires .NET Framework version(3.5 and above) supporting WCF. TCPBinding supports a variety of features, including reliability, transactions, and security.

**Framework**
-- .Net 3.5 or above.

**Security**
 -- Basic/Windows Authentication.

**Access**
  -- Creating proxy (svcutil/Channelfactory) is enough to access the Selfhosted wcf service.

**Others**
  -- does not require IIS or any other service

Hope this help .. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647180.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, WCF self hosting means self hosting. You are not dependent on either IIS or WPA.

Take a look at [this link on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx). You use the ServiceHost mentioned in point 8 to make the actual hosting component.

Below is a snippet that self-hosts a WCF service as a HTTP service.

```
  var baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:3124/");
  var host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(SSOUser), baseAddress);
  var sep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISSOUser), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
  sep.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
  host.Open();
```

What you may miss - as compared to IIS hosting etc - is that you will need to put the service host in a running application or a windows service to make it listen on the endpoint continuosly. But that probably doesn't surprise you :)

Answer (score 0):

any addition component. wcf selfhost required framework 3/3.5/4/4.5 only